# why do the two different ways of initialising objects give different outputs

Tags: c++, constructor, static-members

Consider the following code

```
#include <iostream> 
    using namespace std; 

    class A 
    { 
        int x; 
    public: 
        A() { cout << "A's constructor called " << endl; } 
    }; 

    class B 
    { 
        public:
        static A a; 

        B() { cout << "B's constructor called " << endl; } 
        static A getA() { return a; } 
    }; 

    A B::a; // definition of a 

    int main() 
    { 
        B b1, b2, b3; 
        A a = b1.getA(); 

        cout<<&a<<endl;  

        cout<<&B::a;

        return 0; 
    }
```

the output is

```
A's constructor called 
B's constructor called 
B's constructor called 
B's constructor called 
0x7fff03081280
0x601194
```

Now lets consider another similar code

```
    #include <iostream> 
    using namespace std; 

    class A 
    { 
        int x; 
    public: 
        A() { cout << "A's constructor called " << endl; } 
    }; 

    class B 
    { 
        public:
        static A a; 

        B() { cout << "B's constructor called " << endl; } 
        static A getA() { return a; } 
    }; 

    A B::a; // definition of a 

    int main() 
    { 
        B b1, b2, b3; 
        A a ;
        a= b1.getA(); 

        cout<<&a<<endl;  
        cout<<&B::a;  

        return 0; 
    }
```

the output is

```
A's constructor called 
B's constructor called 
B's constructor called 
B's constructor called 
A's constructor called 
0x7ffc485a1070
0x601194
```

Now my question is that why in the first case the constructor of A is called only once , whereas in the second code its called twice.

Also the two  output &a and &B::a are different so it means they are two different objects .

Please explain why this is so.

Answer (score 3):

In your first code

> ```
> A a = b1.getA();
> ```

the copy-constructor of `A` gets called which doesn't generate any output. Define it yourself and you'll get a similar output to your second code.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, `B::a` is B's (public) static member instance of otherwise quite an usual class `A`. So, the first `A`'s constructor logged is that of `B::a`, which should be initialized before control enters `main`, but next you create a separate instance of `A` local to `main`, it is constructed in order alongside with other `main`'s local variables (here, right after all the `B`s) and it is naturally distinct from `B::a`.

Answer (score 1):

> Now my question is that why in the first case the constructor of A is called only once , whereas in the second code its called twice.

Because in the first case you default-initialised only the static `B::a`, and copy-initialised the local `a`.

In the second you default-initialised both objects.

The crucial difference is that you only print a message in the default constructor, and don't print anything in the copy constructor.

> Also the two output &a and &B::a are different so it means they are two different objects .

That is correct. `a` is a local variable, while `B::a` is a static member variable. They are different objects.

Answer (score 1):

Static member variables of class type represent a storage with process-wide life span. It gets initialized as such, at some point before entry point to program - the beginning of main() - is reached. That's the first constructor call.

The line

```
A a = b1.getA();
```

initializes object a by calling copy constructor and through  return value optimization and copy elision there is no default constructor call.

The second variant:

```
A a;            // A() call
a = b1.getA();  // operator= call
```

Modified class

```
class A 
{ 
    int x; 
public: 
    A(const A& a): x(a.x) { cout << "A's copy constructor called " << endl; } 
    A(A&& a): x(a.x) { a.x = 0; cout << "A's move constructor called " << endl; }
    const A& operator=(const A& a) { x = a.x; cout << "A's copy operator= called " << endl; } 
    A() { cout << "A's constructor called " << endl; } 
};
```

would give this output in first case:

```
A's constructor called 
B's constructor called 
B's constructor called 
B's constructor called 
A's copy constructor called
```

And second case would result in:

```
A's constructor called 
B's constructor called 
B's constructor called 
B's constructor called 
A's constructor called 
A's copy constructor called 
A's copy operator= called
```

Answer (score 0):

It is simple to understand that whenever the class instance (object) getting created associated constructor is getting called.

> Now my question is that why in the first case the constructor of A is called only once , whereas in the second code its called twice.

You are creating second object directly in stack and constructor is getting called in later case, first one is the static and second one by creating object in stack by below statement.

```
A a ;
```

In first case, instead of constructor, copy constructor is getting called so thats why you are not getting the print statement second time.

```
A a = b1.getA();
```

Comment: There are two separate objects in both cases.

Comment: What does this add to the previous answers?